# LinqToEntities code for Query needing one entity returned foreach root node?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities, relational-database, domainservices

I think I have got myself into a muddle with this one. My database looks like:

```
Locations [root]
    Inspections [level1]
       InspectionItems [level2]
           InspectionReadings [level3]      
    Areas [level1]
       Inspections [level2]
           InspectionItems [level3]
               InspectionReadings [level4]
```

each table is linked by Guid to the previous table and the Inspections table has nullable AreaID so that it can be a direct child of Locations.

What I need is

```
for each Location 
    {take all InspectionReadings entities
     where location == location
     sort date descending 
     return the top Entity details}
add the Location details and the InspectionReading details into a new table
return new table
```

the result should be a datagrid with a list of locations and their latest inspection reading date. each location should only appear once.

What I have managed is (this is in my DomainService.cs)

```
        public IQueryable<LocationStatusList> GetLocationStatus()
        {
         var status = (from a in ObjectContext.Locations
                      from b in ObjectContext.InspectionReadings
                      orderby b.DateTaken descending, a.Name 
                      select new LocationStatusList()
                      {
                          ID = b.ID,
                          LocationName = a.Name,
                          LastInspectionDate = b.DateTaken ?? DateTime.MinValue, // the data is nullable so it needs a value to return in that case
                          StatusNumber = b.Status ?? -1 // the data is nullable so it needs a value to return in that case
                      });
         return status;
        }
```

which returns the entire InspectionItems entities with their relevant location and although I've tried I can't find a way of doing what I need.

I would like to do all the code for this in the DomainService class but the only way I can think at the moment is to give the query each location name as a parameter from a viewmodel, return a single entity and create a new list and add each single entity.

Surely this can all be done in a LINQ query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final version, if I get it right:

```
var status = (from a in ObjectContext.Locations
              select new {Location = a, LastReading = a.Inspections.SelectMany(i=>i.InspectionReadings).OrderBy(r=>r.PostDate).FirstOrDefault()};
```

Comment: Thanks! I can see how this would work, unfortunately my InspectionReadings table is not a direct child of my Inspections table so it throws an error on .SelectMany as it cannot find the key relationship.  

InspectionReadings has an InspectionItemsID,  
InspectionItems has an InspectionID,  
so there's an extra level in the hierarchy.  

I need something like:  

    LastReading = a.Inspections.SelectMany(i=>i.InspectionItems.SelectMany(j=>j.InspectionReadings).OrderBy(r=>r.DateTaken).FirstOrDefault())  

Can you help?

Comment: It throws an error 'The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.'

Comment: Ok try this: `from l in Locations from i in l.Inspestions from ii in i.InspestionItems from ir in ii.InspectionReadings

Comment: I have found the solution!!! Thank you so much for your help - it needed a little tweeking but now it gives exactly what I want. I'll put it as the answer but you get an upvote for giving me the bit I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this:

```
 var result = from l in Locations 
       from i in l.Inspestions 
       from ii in i.InspestionItems 
       from ir in ii.InspectionReadings 
       group ir by l into g 
       select new {Location = g.Key, LastReading = g.OrderBy(r=>r.DateTaken).LastOrDefault() };
```

Last or default for the reason that default sort order is ascending and you need most recent(last).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Val, the code I now have is :

```
public IQueryable<LocationStatusList> GetLocationStatus()
{
   var status = (from a in ObjectContext.Locations
                 select new LocationStatusList
                 {
                    ID=a.ID,
                    Name=a.Name,
                    LastInspectionDate= (from b in ObjectContext.Inspections
                                         from c in ObjectContext.InspectionReadings
                                         where c.InspectionItemID==b.ID && b.LocationID==a.ID
                                         orderby c.DateTaken descending
                                         select c.DateTaken).FirstOrDefault()??DateTime.MinValue,


                    StatusNumber =  (from b in ObjectContext.Inspections
                                     from c in ObjectContext.InspectionReadings
                                     where c.InspectionItemID==b.ID && b.LocationID==a.ID
                                     orderby c.DateTaken descending
                                     select c.Status).FirstOrDefault()??-1,
                 });
   return status;
}
```

which gives precisely what I need. Thank you!